# Wifi device fails, requiring reboot to go online again on NUC

Tags: 14.04, wireless

My wifi device driver fails intermittently when I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My wifi card is an intel one.
I can't seem to get it to work again without rebooting.

Things I've tried:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi iwldvm
sudo modprobe iwldvm iwlwifi
```

Turning Wireless N off in iwlwifi.conf.

Here is a representative dmesg:
http://pastebin.com/1mG4tVwx

Here is the relevant output from lshw:

```
       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            logical name: wlan0
            version: 24
            serial: b4:b6:76:5f:ea:7e
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0
            resources: irq:62 memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of steps I suggest. First, I notice this in the pastebin:

> Hardware name:                  /D54250WYK, BIOS
>   WYLPT10H.86A.0021.2013.1017.1606 10/17/2013

There is an updated BIOS available here: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24881/BIOS-Update-WYLPT10H-86A- I suggest you update it.

Second, I notice this:

```
[ 4952.966651] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 4952.977497] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 4952.977501] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
```

I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2  Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=XX
```

Of course, substitute your country code for XX. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

After these steps, reboot. If the symptoms persist, give us an updated pastebin and I'll edit my answer to propose more steps.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! In the release notes of the BIOS I saw text describing the problem I encountered. I installed it, hopefully the issue will be resolved.